# IMAPStore connection using JavaMail with Microsoft Exchange server is slow

Tags: jakarta-mail, imap

Using geronimo-javamail_1.4_mail-1.8.3 for connecting and fetching emails from IMAP Servers.

The code used to connect IMAPStore is as below:

```
    Properties props = System.getProperties();

    if (port == 143)
        props.setProperty("mail.store.protocol", "imap");
    else
        props.setProperty("mail.store.protocol", "imaps");


    props.setProperty("mail.store.port", port + "");

    Session session = Session.getInstance(props, null);
    //session.setDebug(true);

    IMAPStore store = null;

    if (port == 143)
        store = new IMAPStore(session, null);
    else
        store = new IMAPSSLStore(session, null);

    store.connect(serverName, userName, password);
```

The store connection for Gmail is fast, it takes around 3 secs, but for connecting Microsoft Exchange Server (e.g., outlook.office365.com) is taking 15-20 secs constantly.

Do I need to include any other properties? How to optimize store connection with Exchange servers?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe that server is just slow?

You might also want to try the [JavaMail reference implementation](https://java.net/projects/javamail/pages/Home) instead of the GNU version.

Also, you shouldn't be instantiating the Store objects yourself; you should use session.getStore("imap").  To control SSL or no SSL, use props.put("mail.imap.ssl.enable", "true"/"false").

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I changed properties as you said. Also I observed fetching messages is also taking time. I fetch messages using       FetchProfile fetchProfile = new FetchProfile();
     fetchProfile.add(FetchProfile.Item.ENVELOPE);
     inbox.fetch(messages, fetchProfile)

Comment: Did you also switch to the JavaMail RI?  Using the fetch method can prefetch some data for a bunch of messages all at once, reducing overhead by eliminating many round trips to the server.  If your performance is still poor, examine the debug output to make sure you're not doing extra operations.  You also might want to time stamp the debug output (perhaps using java.util.logging) to see how long it takes the server to respond to messages.

Comment: Hi Bill, I swiched to JavaMail and tested, getContent() from each Message object is consuming more time. Even fetch method fetches all messages, why again it is taking time to fetch content. Can we reduce this time?

Comment: Post the [debug output](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#debug) with the timing information.

Comment: I didn't notice any unnecessary operations in the debug output except for possibly the fetch of the Newsgroups header.  Which operations are taking longer than you expect?  If you connect to Gmail instead, how long do those operations take on Gmail?  If it's just that your server is too slow, you'll need to contact your server administrator.